# Firebase duplicate classes error after update

Tags: android, firebase

Everything works with `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4` version , but there's a newer one and when i update it to `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5` in gradle and then run my app this error appears

```
   org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\AppName\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0.jar
Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
    Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdz
```

That's my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.test"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.2'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The latest `firebase-core` is version 16.0.4, you can check the latest version of each dependency in the following link:

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Comment: You're right, that's not what my android studio was telling me, i think i got too used to not even double checking things [Link](https://imgur.com/a/Xovd30A)

Comment: I see.. it's still not listed in the release note and in the get started part of the firebase website. It is listed in google maven repository ( can check in this link and navigate to the com.google.firebase https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html) which means they did release it, but maybe better to keep using 16.0.4 until they add it in the release note website.

Comment: I had to go back to play-services-ads:16.0.0 from 17.0.0. The rest of my dependencies are up to date; so no lint warnings and yes 16.0.5. Hopefully this will save someone a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

## Fix: insert this into `app/build.gradle`

Applies to react native firebase `v25.12.0` so ensure update to this.

insert into `dependencies` section

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-image-label-model:20.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-face-contour-internal:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-image-labeling-internal:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-image-label:18.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-face-model:20.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-model-interpreter:22.0.4'
```

ref: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/commit/dc4f57a952a7076a48a224087c9a8e7cdeaf4afc#diff-8a85188c69631f3ee1d3b09e01cdfcffae515432e9efdfb74683b880a8902172